# AzureFileCop@5 #error# The term 'Get-AzResource' is not recognized "yaml"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-file-copy

trying to create pipeline which pushes github repository files to blob storage.
After yesterday surfing I was able to get away from Az.Accounts module not found (though it is installed in VM).
As suggested on stack overflow AzureRM and az was giving conflicts. After doing Uninstall-AzureRm on VM.
I have reached this far & below is output from pipeline:

Starting: AzureFileCopy
Task : Azure file copy
Description : Copy files to Azure Blob Storage or virtual machines
Version : 5.210.1
Author : Microsoft Corporation
Help : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy
Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Accounts\1.7.0\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant xx-xx-xx-xx-xx -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx -TenantId xxx-xxx-xx-xx
Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
##[error]The term 'Get-AzResource' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Finishing: AzureFileCopy

Your valuable input / help will ease my day.
BR,/Mubeen

Comment: I reverted my task to use version AzureFileCopy@3. Also removed Az module not in use with version3. Missing module AzureRM installed to VM with PowerShell ISE.